# Print content of popup dialong by javascript in backbone project

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, iframe, jasper-reports

I have a button in and it is used for calling a dialog. Dialog's content is a pdf got from `jasper report`.

Here is the backbone view of dialog :

```
var framSrc = getRSUR; //getting pdf from jasper reporting server
var ReportView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName : "div",
  id : "report",
  initialize: function() {
  },
  events : {
    'click #print' : 'printDialog'
  },
  'printDialog' : function(){
      printReport();
  },
  render: function(){
    this.$el.html('<div><a id="print"><img src="printer.png" width="30px"><span style="position:relative;bottom:10px; left:10px;">Print Report</span></a></div><iframe id="agingFrame" src="'+framSrc+'"></iframe>');
    return this;
  }
});
```

**printReport()** :

```
function printReport(){
  try{
    var oIframe = document.getElementById('agingFrame');
    var oContent = document.getElementById('agingFrame').innerHTML;
    var oDoc = (oIframe.contentWindow || oIframe.contentDocument);
    if (oDoc.document) oDoc = oDoc.document;
    oDoc.write("<html><head><title>title</title>");
    oDoc.write("</head><body onload='this.focus(); this.print();'>");
    oDoc.write(oContent + "</body></html>");
    oDoc.close();
  }
  catch(e){
      self.print();
  }
 }
```

But what I've got from printing is the full page of the web page, not the pdf content in iframe.

Comment: Is it going into your catch?

Comment: @artm : Did you mean pdf content?

Comment: No. The try catch you have, is it failing the code and running self.print() in your catch statement?

Comment: @artm : Ah yeah! self.print() is running. But what is the problem with the try() block anyway, I have no idea.

Comment: Change your catch to catch(e) { alert(e.name + ' ' + e.message); } to see what the error is. Also why don't you debug the try code with developer tools?

Comment: @artm : I got the point of problem, `Error Permission denied to access property 'document'` in Firefox and `SecurityError Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame` in chrome.

Comment: Ah so the iFrame is from another domain? Not sure how to print accros domain frames. Is it possible to change the frame to it's on the same domain as the page?

Comment: @artm  : iFrame is the same domain as the page, but the `src` of iFrame is got from the other domain, can not change.

Comment: Not sure if this'll work but maybe you can try something like var window = window.open(iframeUrl, "_blank"); window.print(); You won't be able to get src from iframe thou but you might have it in a variable.

Comment: Doing that, an error appeared `TypeError: window is undefined
 

var window = window.open(framSrc, "_blank");`

Comment: var newWindow = window.open(framSrc, "_blank");

Comment: @artm : I don't want to open a new window beside the frame. Any possible way avoid that?

Comment: This may or may not be acceptable, creates a new window and closes it after printing it. var newWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com.au", "_blank", 'toolbar=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,left=0, top=0, width=1, height=1', '');
newWindow.print();
newWindow.close();

Comment: @artm It can be acceptable.. looks worse than expected.

Comment: Not sure how else to print an across domain iframe. Google might help.